# Set a different background color for weekends in a date axis using plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I am using `plot.ly` within `r` to display a time series in which I have dates on the X axis (see code below). I would also like to highlight the weekends, most likely using a darker background. I know that I can set a background colour using `layout`, but AFAIK this applies to all the plot area, not a particular region.

Is there any way to use a different background colour for weekends in an horizontal axis with dates like in the image below?

[image]

```r
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datadista/datasets/master/COVID%2019/nacional_covid19.csv")               


plot_ly(data = df) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~ fecha,
            y = ~ casos,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines+markers",
            name = "Contagios detectados") %>% 
  layout(title = "My title",
         legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
         hovermode = "compare")
```

This is the dataframe:

```
> tail(df)
        fecha  casos altas fallecimientos ingresos_uci hospitalizados
32 2020-03-27  64059  9357           4858         4165          36293
33 2020-03-28  72248 12285           5690         4575          40630
34 2020-03-29  78797 14709           6528         4907          43397
35 2020-03-30  85195 16780           7340         5231          46617
36 2020-03-31  94417 19259           8189         5607          49243
37 2020-04-01 102136 22647           9053         5872          51418
```

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(fecha = structure(1:37, .Label = c("2020-02-25", 
"2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", 
"2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", 
"2020-03-07", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", 
"2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", 
"2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", 
"2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", 
"2020-04-01"), class = "factor"), casos = c(3L, 10L, 16L, 32L, 
44L, 66L, 114L, 135L, 198L, 237L, 365L, 430L, 589L, 999L, 1622L, 
2128L, 2950L, 4209L, 5753L, 7753L, 9191L, 11178L, 13716L, 17147L, 
19980L, 24926L, 28572L, 33089L, 39673L, 47610L, 56188L, 64059L, 
72248L, 78797L, 85195L, 94417L, 102136L), altas = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23L, 135L, 183L, 189L, 
189L, 517L, 517L, 530L, 1028L, 1081L, 1107L, 1585L, 2125L, 2575L, 
3355L, 3794L, 5367L, 7015L, 9357L, 12285L, 14709L, 16780L, 19259L, 
22647L), fallecimientos = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 8L, 17L, 17L, 35L, 47L, 84L, 120L, 136L, 288L, 309L, 
491L, 598L, 767L, 1002L, 1326L, 1720L, 2182L, 2696L, 3434L, 4089L, 
4858L, 5690L, 6528L, 7340L, 8189L, 9053L), ingresos_uci = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 9L, 11L, NA, NA, 68L, 100L, 142L, 
190L, 272L, 293L, 382L, 432L, 563L, 774L, 939L, 1141L, 1612L, 
1785L, 2355L, 2636L, 3166L, 3679L, 4165L, 4575L, 4907L, 5231L, 
5607L, 5872L), hospitalizados = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3215L, 
5717L, NA, 10542L, 13282L, 15554L, 18374L, 22762L, 26960L, 31912L, 
36293L, 40630L, 43397L, 46617L, 49243L, 51418L)), .Names = c("fecha", 
"casos", "altas", "fallecimientos", "ingresos_uci", "hospitalizados"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```

And this is the output plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea I have here is adding polygons for weekends, which would be similar to different backgrounds for weekends.

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Creating a dataset for polygons with weekend dates
data.frame(fecha=as.Date(df1$fecha), day=weekdays(as.Date(df1$fecha))) %>% 
  filter(day %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = day, values_from = fecha) %>% 
  unnest() -> df2

df1 %>% 
  mutate(fecha = as.Date(fecha)) %>% 
plot_ly(data = .) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~ fecha,
            y = ~ casos,
            type = "scatter",
            mode = "lines+markers",
            name = "Contagios detectados") %>% 
  layout(title = "My title",
         legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
         hovermode = "compare") -> p


for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  p <- add_polygons(p, x = c(df2[[i, "Saturday"]], df2[[i, "Saturday"]], 
                             df2[[i, "Sunday"]], df2[[i, "Sunday"]]), 
                       y = c(0, max(df1$casos), max(df1$casos), 0), 
                       hoverinfo = "none", color = I("blue"), showlegend = F, 
                       hoveron = "points", opacity = 0.5)
} 

p
```

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity, what does de I in color = I("blue") means? is there any way to remove the border?